# Managing Cancelable Partial Updates using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm

I’m new to MVVM and am trying to establish good practices as I convert a large non-Model-View WinForms project. Here’s an example of a solution I’ve implemented. I’m wondering if there is a better pattern for solving this class of problem.

MyModel has ten properties. MyView exposes two of them for users to update. MyViewModel handles the usual stuff in between.

Other models depend on MyModel’s properties, so I only want to change MyModel when values are committed to. MyView has OK and Cancel buttons, so instead of having MyViewModel directly update MyModel when the user interacts with MyView, I’ve created another layer: MyTempModel. MyTempModel contains two properties which correspond to the two from MyModel.

So inside MyModel, prompting code looks something like this:

```
var tempModel = new TempModel{Prop1=Prop1,Prop2=Prop2};
bool? response = new MyView().ShowDialog();
if (response.HasValue && response.Value)
{
    Prop1 = tempModel.Prop1
    Prop2 = tempModel.Prop2
}
```

Thus if the user clicks ‘Cancel’, MyModel’s properties are not changed.
Note: Not shown here is that I set a reference to MyTempModel in MyViewModel once to establish that wiring. MyViewModel subscribes to property changed events in MyTempModel and MyView uses databinding to connect to MyViewModel.

model - > view data flow summary:
MyModel sets property in MyTempModel, which fires an event. MyViewModel’s evenhandler picks up the change and sets a dependency property, causing MyView to update.

view -> model data flow summary:
Changes to MyView result in dependency property in MyViewModel to change. This property’s setter pushes the value to MyTempModel. When user clicks Ok then MyModel copies values from MyTempModel.

I'm particularly interested in the role of the ViewModel. I have in mind that keeping dialogs "humble" is a good thing, and maybe that is spilling over into making ViewModels humble. So comments on what kind of functionality you put into your view models vs your domain models would be especially interesting.

I appreciate any and all design wisdom for this pattern. I'll gladly update this info if anyone needs clarification.

Comment: Why do you need this `TempModel`when translating between `MyView` and `MyModel` is typically the task of your `MyViewModel`? Note that a view model should be optimized for dealing with a specific view. Your `MyModel` should be oblivious to the existence of any specific view or view model and definitely should not be dealing with some kind of `TempModel` that is needed for a specific view. It is the task of `MyViewModel` to deal with these interaction scenarios such as cancellation.

Comment: @Alex: So are you saying all I need to do is to defer pushing changes from ViewModel to Model until the user clicks OK? Also, use of TempModel isn't View-specific; it's just a subset of Model that isolates it.

Comment: Yes, as a general rule, your view model should deal with coordinating changes and cancellation. Unless the fact that the user cancelled an action is worthwhile capturing in your domain, your model should not have a reason to see any changes. Also, you mentioned that `TempModel` was created specifically to serve this view / cancellation scenario. Are you saying it is also used for other purposes?

Comment: Could you please clarify 'MyViewModel has OK and Cancel buttons'? Is that a typo, a reference to Command bindings for OK and Cancel, or do you have OK and Cancel buttons in your ViewModel?

Comment: @Alex: I just meant that the TempModel isn't meant to be specific for this view but you're right that it really only exists to handle the cancellation scenario. I added a para near the end of my post that describes what I was thinking.

Comment: @goobering: Sorry, yeah, just a typo. Buttons are in my xaml and command handlers are in the view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the use of a proxy class is a bad thing. I'm a little concerned about this: 'MyModel sets property in MyTempModel, which fires an event. MyViewModel’s evenhandler picks up the change and sets a dependency property, causing MyView to update.' I think that renders your Model classes a little less universal and obscures that functionality from the ViewModel. I would just use the ViewModel to mediate the swap in/out of the proxy, rather than having the Models do it. I also think that using a proxy opens up use of DataTemplates for that type which could make the UI work easier.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the direction given by Alex is to make the viewmodel a representation of what is in both client and server side.

E.g., the number shown is always what the user entered and the background of the number indicates that this number has been confirmed or not (pending)by the server. The viewmodel could use two different properties to contain these values and a status property to indicate the fact the property has been synchronized.

This way the viewmodel captures all the user needs to know. All the view needs to do is bind to the correct properties for display and editing.

Comment: I think this will work well for a relatively small number of properties. As that number grows it's going to get pretty complicated to manage everything.

Comment: @goobering, that goes for any ViewModel really. Viewmodels with a lot of properties can be a pain to maintain. In those cases I turn to T4 templates and generate the VM properties, command, etc.

Comment: It's not so much the generation that I'm concerned about as the ongoing logistics. If you used this approach for, for example, 3 object types, each of which has 10 properties that could be edited. That's 60 properties to handle in your ViewModel. If, instead, you just use proxy classes to hold the non-committed data then you're only dealing with 6 (Thing1, Thing1Edit, Thing2, Thing2Edit, Thing3, Thing3Edit).

Comment: @goobering: I'm curious, are you saying my use of a proxy class is a good thing? I got the impression from Alex that it was not in line with MVVM philosophy.

Comment: I don't think the use of a proxy class is a bad thing. I'm a little concerned about this: 'MyModel sets property in MyTempModel, which fires an event. MyViewModel’s evenhandler picks up the change and sets a dependency property, causing MyView to update.' I think that renders your Model classes a little less universal and obscures that functionality from the ViewModel. I would just use the ViewModel to mediate the swap in/out of the proxy, rather than having the Models do it. I also think that using a proxy opens up use of DataTemplates for that type which could make the UI work easier.

Comment: @goobering: If you copy your last comment into an answer, I'll select it.